# Swift: "Any" does not have member named element

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

So not sure what is wrong here, but swift throws me error in this case, and gives me no output for `foo[0]`

```
let bar: [String: Any] = [
    "questions":[
        ["id":1,"text":"What is your name?"],
        ["id":2,"text":"What is the last name?"]
    ],
    "status":"baz",
    "registered": true
]

let foo: [[String: Any]] = bar["questions"] as [[String: Any]]

foo[0]
```

Although it does work if I do following -

```
let bar: [String: String] = [
    "questions":[
        ["id":"1","text":"What is your name?"],
        ["id":"2","text":"What is the last name?"]
    ],
    "status":"AUTHENTICATE",
    "registered": true
]

let foo: [[String: String]] = bar["questions"] as [[String: String]]

foo[0]
```

I changed my ids to string (notice I have not touched boolean) and also Any to string.

Please shed some light for this behavior.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a complicated dictionary literal like `["id":1,"text":"What is your name?"]` without annotating the type in some way it will default to creating an `NSDictionary`.

`NSDictionary` in Swift is bridged to `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. Force casting it to `[String: Any]` will crash with error "can't reinterpretCast values of different sizes". But casting `NSDictionary` to `[String: AnyObject]` will work just fine.

So you can either use `[String: AnyObject]` or `NSDictionary` instead of `[String: Any]`, or you can hint the type of desired dictionaries, for example like this:

```
let bar: [String: Any] = [
    "questions":[
        ["id":1,"text":"What is your name?"] as [String: Any],
        ["id":2,"text":"What is the last name?"]
    ],
    "status":"baz",
    "registered": true
]
```

or like this

```
let bar: [String: Any] = [
    "questions":[
        ["id":1,"text":"What is your name?"],
        ["id":2,"text":"What is the last name?"]
    ] as [[String: Any]],
    "status":"baz",
    "registered": true
]
```

Comment: It does work but I am still trying to wrap my head around `Any`. What good is `Any` or `AnyObject` or `Dictionary` in general if it cannot handle complex patterns. FYI - The above throws error even if I use `AnyObject`. Maybe I need to a better understanding of underlying API.

Comment: Indeed it crashes for `[String: AnyObject]` if you don't make bar of this type as well. Oh and you might also need to unwrap the result of subscript like this `bar["questions"]!` because it returns an optional.